# Mongo 2.6.3 does not start on init

Tags: mongodb, upstart, ubuntu-14.04

On fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04, I have installed mongodb 2.6.3 from mongo [package](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/),
problem is, that it does not start on reboot. It starts normally when I do

```
sudo service mongod start
```

and there are no errors in log file. 
but when I reboot, log file has no new entries and

```
service mongod status
```

produces

```
mongod stop/waiting
```

I have tried mongod --repair, with no effect. I have tried fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04, as I thought that my older many times upgraded OS might have something wrong with it, but nothing changed.

With older version mongo that comes from ubuntu package manager, everything was starting up nicely.

Can you please give some advice on where to look to fix this issue and make mongod start up when system is booted up. Thanks!

Comment: 1. do you have sudo rights to this box? 2. have you tried manually starting mongod for example $ sudo /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod ? (or whatever your path is for the mongod process)

Comment: 1. yes, it is my primary pc 2. it works when manually started, no error messages in log, works perfectly. only issue is with upstart.

Comment: I would make sure that your data directory & files, log directory & files and the pid file (see the /etc/init.d/mongod file for location) are all read/write for your mongod user. It is likely to be a problem either with the log or pid file if you are not seeing log output.

Comment: why did you install it from source and not from their repo? If it is for a specific version usage, you can do that through `apt` with the right policy.

Comment: i did install it from their repo. Maybe I worded my sentence a bit wrong. I meant that I did not take it from Ubuntu package manager, but directly from 10gen

Comment: @MartinsUntals Can you please verify that only `mongodb-org` and its dependencies are installed? `sudo dpkg -l | grep mongo` if you see `mongodb-10gen`, this could be part of the problem.

Comment: only mongodb-org

`mongodb-org        2.6.3 amd64 MongoDB open source document-oriented database system (metapackage)
mongodb-org-mongos 2.6.3 amd64 MongoDB sharded cluster query router
mongodb-org-server 2.6.3 amd64 MongoDB database server
mongodb-org-shell  2.6.3 amd64 MongoDB shell client
mongodb-org-tools  2.6.3 amd64 MongoDB tools`

Comment: Hey what is the output of `sudo initctl show-config mongodb`.

Comment: for `mongodb` it is `unknown job: mongodb`, for `sudo initctl show-config mongodb` it is `mongod
  start on runlevel [2345]
  stop on runlevel [06]`

Comment: can you check if the mongod process is running on restart "ps -ef | grep mongod" and post the output here? Do you see anything in dmesg / syslog that could indicate a failed service?

Comment: nothing in dmesg and syslog about any failures. running ps -ef | grep mongod after reboot produces no processes except grep.

Comment: How does a restart happen? Is that a hard restart? Or is MongoDB stopped before restart? The only other thing is PID file is somehow not removed during restart and start may consider as if other mongod instance is already running etc.

Comment: Restart is normal shutdown/restart. nothing special. no hard reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem. In the log file there was an:

```
************
Unclean shutdown detected
Please visit http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair for recovery instructions.
************
```

To solve this error, I just removed the lock file and it worked again.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

Comment: I can not confirm or deny this solution, as problem solved itself after full system reinstall and new version of both mongo and ubuntu. However, it does sound correct, so I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that mongo upstart job checks if mongo is installed by the package manager. You need to edit the upstart job to use the new from-source binary location (which I think is /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod).

Comment: if I run service mongod start then it works. So upstart job is fine, if I understnad it correctly